# What does バーターmean?

Tags: words, katakana

In a meeting, I heard this word バーター many times.

The conversation was like below:
バーターを含めると売り上げが上がっていますが、含めない場合、下がります。

What I understood from the context is that word is related to accounting (business)

I tried searching in dictionary also still couldn't understand.
http://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC

Could someone please help me to understand the meaning of this word, and where it is used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

バーター has two major meanings:

- *barter* or 物々交換, as described in English Wikipedia article [barter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barter)
- *cross-selling*, *tying arrangement*, *packaged deal*, バンドル商法 or 抱き合わせ as described [here](http://www.excite.co.jp/News/column_g/20160120/B_chive_bartar-towa-nanika.html) and [here](http://news.livedoor.com/article/detail/6418773/). Etymologically it's **an anagram of 束** (たば, "bundle").

Personally, I'm rather familiar with the *latter* sense because it's fairly common in gossip columns. If you work in the showbiz industry, it's almost certainly the latter. I think I have seen バーター used in the latter sense outside of the showbiz industry a few times.

---

Some examples of バーター in the latter sense on the net (most are about 芸能人, but I picked examples outside the 芸能界 here):

> #### [EMOBILE LTE - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=EMOBILE_LTE&oldid=62325838)
>
> Nexus 7 (2013)…Cellularモデルについては、イー・アクセスからの発売はされず、Google Playでの購入か、MVNO提供プロバイダからの提供により使用可能。販売店によっては、Wi-Fiモデルについて、**データ端末とのバーターで販売された**ケースも散見された。
>
> #### [誰かの落し物 第2話](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/1177354054881180235/episodes/1177354054882068321)
>
> 並んで待って、5分ぐらいで列は進んで自分の番が回ってくる。見ると、明太子がこれでもかと詰められた容器が狭しと並んでいる。その隣には、「今だけ１００円！」と銘打った燻製のイカまで。やはり大阪人、**抱き合せ、バーター商法**にも弱い。明太の形が整って、量の多そうな容器を選んで店員さんに「イカも一緒に」と言って手渡す。
>
> #### [ECCビジネススクール 販売単価アップを成功させる３つの方法](http://ecc-business.jp/2016/10/06/post-465/)
>
> まず第一がクロスセルです。これは**バーター**商法といって古くから行われているスキルです。つまり『ついで買い』を誘導する方法になります。駅弁屋さんがお茶やミカンを一緒に販売している、あのやり方です。これは注文の品だけをお出しするのではなく、それに関連する商品・サービスをもう一つお勧めする方法で、単価の安いファーストフードでお馴染みでしょう。

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. It makes my understanding clear.